# Problem while burning Ubuntu iso file on a DVD-R on Windows 7

Tags: 16.04, iso, dvd, burning

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows 7 laptop. The laptop is a 64 bits one. I downloaded the iso image file but then when trying to burn it into a DVD driver I got the error "The burning could not be done because of an error. Error code : 0x8007045D".

Any idea of what this mean and how can I solve it ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: what software are you using to  burn the DVD?